# in robot framewerk text edit using selenium library

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library, robotframework-ide

This is an issue I'm facing while automating my test case via robot framework, I'm trying to click on the Action column of 3rd row in the below table (screenshot below)
[image]

The Xpath I'm using is as below

```
    Click element xpath=.//table[id="mylogiusers"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[37] 
    ${table_cell} Get Table Cell xpath=//table[contains(@id,'mylogiusers')]
    Click Link ${table_cell}
```

Note - there are multiple hidden columns in the table, so though the Action column appears to be 10th but in the html table it's number 37, so added td[37] in above xpath.

This is a bootstrap table, please let me know where I'm going wrong, tried multiple options in xpath but none seems to be working here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So, what happens when you run your code?

Comment: do you mean you are not able to identify that web element using xpath?

Comment: I would try to search the entry I need and after the search, when you have just an entry, you could click the first Action Button.